# Question about for loops in turtle functions and also in general

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

### Question about for loops in general:

I am new to Python was wondering what the purpose of "for loops" is? What do they do in a function/what output do they produce? When are they used?

(I've done some research on what a for loop is, but most sources are confusing/unclear so I decided to ask on here.)

### Question about using for loops in turtle:

Is the for loop function required in the following code dealing with filling in colors of a shape? I've seen some people use it when demonstrating examples of filling in color, but I'm not quite sure if it's required or what it does.

```
# Example code: I know, nothing is shown 
# because I haven't told the function to draw anything, this is just an example.

t.pencolor("blue")
t.fillcolor("blue")
t.begin_fill()
for i in range(4):
    # remove 'pass' and write some code here, for loop is not doing any thing.
    pass
t.end_fill()

# I noticed that this code produced the same output as:

t.pencolor("blue")
t.fillcolor("blue")
t.begin_fill()
t.end_fill()
```

Comment: With no indentation after the `for i in range(4):`, your for-loop has nothing in it.

Comment: sorry it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You use a `for` loop whenever you need to do the same thing over and over<sup>(a)</sup>.

For example (using your "turtle" area of concern), say you wanted to draw a circle (or something approximating a circle). You could do this with something like:

```
pen down
for i in 1..360:
    go forward 1 unit
    turn right one degree
pen up
```

The alternative would be a rather long sequence of commands of the form:

```
    got forward 1 unit
    turn right one degree
    got forward 1 unit
    turn right one degree
    got forward 1 unit
    turn right one degree
    : :
    got forward 1 unit
    turn right one degree
```

which *nobody* wants to read or debug :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The way I teach beginners is to basically introduce them to the three main concepts of program flow:

- sequence, doing things sequentially in order;
- iteration, doing a similar thing many times; and
- selection, doing different things based on conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But for my cause what does for "i in range(4):" do? Does it fill the color blue 4 times in the shape or what? because I noticed i get the same result when not having "i in range(4):"

Comment: Not sure about the "same thing"-formulation. I would rather say it's for when you need to do something for a fixed number of iterations.

Comment: so the number in range is the number of times something is gonna be repeated? like for example, for i in range(4), something will be repeated 4 times. Also what does "i" represent? It is not even defined

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(4):
  t.forward(150)
  t.right(90)
```

change range(1), range(2), range(3) then you will be able to see beauty of for loop.

Comment: what does the number mean in the range? Is it the number of times something will be repeated( 4 times) or a number randomly selected from the range 0-4?

Comment: range returns sequence of number. range(0, 4) returns 4 numbers starting from 0 till 4 (not including 4). that means 0, 1, 2, 3, so loop will run 4 times. Similarly range(10, 13) gives 10, 11, 12. In this case loop will run three times.

Comment: for more examples on range, please read https://pynative.com/python-range-function/